# SAS Logistic - Identify and remove outliers

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and trying to identify and remove outliers from the data having 25k rows and 250 columns using logistic regression. Can please someone help me out with my problem.
Thanks

Comment: What's an outlier? There's no specific definition, it depends on context.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really right to just delete outliers that skew your data, so context is especially important if you are going to do that. [This](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001315216.htm) will show how you remove the rows that contain the outliers, and you can do something like this:

```
data removeOutliers;
   set originalData;
   if (col-mean(col))/std(col) > 3 then delete;
run;
```